# How to determine runways at unfamiliar airports?

Tags: pilot-technique, student-pilot

I’m having a hard time determining where the runway is. Let’s say I am 3 NM west of an uncontrolled airport and the runway is 18/36. An the active runway is 18.

What’s the best way to determine where the runway is?

I use the heading but because it still feels unfamiliar.

But to make the runway, I should just turn to a northerly heading that’ll put me on the downwind for that runway make my base turn then runway?

Does anyone have an easier way to do this?

I know you can use ForeFlight but I’m trying not to use it to better my skills.

Comment: In your scenario can you see the airport in order to know you are 3 nm west? Also, do you have avionics that can display the airport (e.g. Garmin or Honeywell, etc.) Or are you saying that you could use foreflight for the display of the airport relative to your current location?

Comment: Adding to the first comment, it is unclear if you are asking about proper pattern entry procedures, or how to acquire the field visually amongst the ground clutter.  In my neck of the woods there are many tall trees, and spotting a small unfamiliar runway when approaching from the side can be a real challenge.  Please clarify the problem.

Comment: I can cannot see the runway vertically but horizontally yes.In this scenario No I don't have avionics. I only have my DG. I know about the entering the pattern at a 45 to the downwind. Im coming from the stand point of having no Knowledge or visual reference of the airport ever other than A chart supplement. The answer cleared it up for me. but sometimes I am just a little unsure about where the runway would be located. I have my DG thats pointed directly west and my runway should be roughly 90deg to the right of me.

Comment: Here's a rather simple trick, look on google maps/earth using a satelaite view and eyeball some ground features coming from the you'll be coming from for real. ie/ prior planning. It really helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first- you should endeavor never to put yourself in this position. By the time you are 3 nautical miles from an airport, you should have long since briefed your traffic pattern entries to the most likely runways (or, ideally, to every possible runway).

If you are in this position, you are behind the airplane. The best thing to do is slow down (mentally, not necessarily your airspeed) and take things one at a time. Fly over the airport well above pattern altitude. Look for traffic in the pattern. Identify the runways and visualize where the various legs of the traffic pattern are. Check that there are no closed runways or vehicles on the runways or anything. Frankly, you should be doing this even if you are ahead of the airplane- there could be NORDO aircraft in the pattern or something obstructing the runway, and you won't know if you just enter the downwind directly.

Don't even think about entering the traffic pattern until you're a few steps ahead of the airplane!

For actually navigating the pattern, a good way is to bug your heading indicator to the runway heading. When you are on downwind on a no-wind day, the bug should be on the bottom of the heading indicator, and it should be 90 degrees to the left or right on crosswind or base. Another way to think about it is that your downwind course should be the same as the heading of the opposite runway- so if you are landing on 18 your heading should be about 360 on downwind.

Keep in mind that you will need to compensate for winds so once you are roughly aligned to a leg of the traffic pattern you should be using ground references to ensure you are flying parallel or perpendicular to the runway.

Joining the traffic pattern as you've described would put you on the right downwind for 18. Unless 18 is designated as right pattern, this is actually illegal per 14 CFR § 91.126(b)(1). The FAA recommended entry to the left downwind is to fly over the field well above pattern altitude until you are a few miles past it, and then make a descending right turn (or a descent followed bu a right turn) and maneuver to join the 45 for the left downwind to 18.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know several things:

1. Where you are in relation to the airport
2. The runway orientation relative to you
3. The traffic pattern being used there.

This is one of those situations were preflight preparation really helps to understand what you’re about to do. Prior to taking off heading for the airport, you need to have considered what the airport layout looks like, and what it’s going to look like from your perspective as you approach it from a certain direction.  Thoroughly read the chart supplement entries for the airport.  ForeFlight also offers 3D tools so you can look at the airport and visualized what it will look like as you fly towards it.  It also can plot traffic patterns and courses for entry into them for ease of reference.  Another excellent reference source are satellite photos of the airport in the surrounding terrain.  An airport may have good, visual, references, nearby, e.g., a sawmill, a Walmart, etc. and you can use the airport’s relation to these references to locate the field.

Airports, especially small ones, are (strangely enough) one of the more difficult objects to spot from the air during VFR ops in both day and night.  This is especially true if you happen to be approaching the runway in a direction perpendicular to it, which is one reason I do not recommend than my students select airports as visual waypoints on VFR cross country flights.  You may have to study the train very carefully, despite the field, but don’t become fixated on that that you ignore other visual duties, such as flying the airplane and seeing and avoiding other traffic.

Once you have determined which runway will be used and have the field in sight, you need to orient yourself to it.  A good way to do this is to use your gyro compass or HSI.  Note where the runway numbers are on the compass face, then draw a line between them in your mind on the face of the compass or HSI.  That line is going to be the orientation of the runway you’ll use relative to you.  Next, note what the traffic pattern is for that runway and *where that traffic pattern will be relative to that runway*

This is just one of the trickier things about entering the pattern at an untowered airport.  I wish I had a hard and fast rule for this, but I’m still in the process of formulating one.  One tip is, if the downwind leg of the traffic pattern is on the opposite side of the runway that you will be using, you were going to use a teardrop entry into the 45° entry onto the downwind leg.  If the downwind leg is on the side of the runway closer to you, you will maneuver the aircraft outside of the traffic pattern such that you can enter on a 45° entry into the downwind leg.

In you example you are 3 nm west of the airfield (I presume headed east).  Since the runway out at the airport is 18/36 and other pilots are reporting they are using Rwy 18 (or the winds in the AWOS/ASOS reports favor using Rwy 18) you know you intend a 45° entry into the downwind.  If the airport is not yet in sight, we can expect the runway to be oriented roughly perpendicular to your direction of flight with the approach end of the runway off to your left.  Next the traffic pattern.  Unless specifically noted on the sectionals and chart supplements, this will be a left hand traffic pattern.  From your orientation, and following the standard VFR traffic pattern entry procedures, you will be entering the patter on thd side of the field opposite to you for a teardrop entry into the left downwind.  This means you will be overflying the field at TPA + 500 feet (direct downwind entries are possible but discouraged at busy uncontrolled airfields for risk of a MAC. Once you have crossed over the airfield and clear of the vicinity of a traffic pattern, start your descent to TPA. Upon reaching TPA, then start your teardrop turn to get onto the 45° entry into the downwind leg.  In this case, you’re going to start a right hand turn until you roll out into the 45° entry.  Since the downwind will be flown on a heading of roughly 360°, You will roll out on a heading of 315°, then turning right with the appropriate spacing to your downwind heading.

Simple, right?  This is one of the finer points of flying into a untowered airports, and it often takes quite a bit of practice to get it right, especially at unfamiliar locations.

Answer (score 0):

You orient the destination airport relative to a more obvious local landmark on your map, like a town or village or lake. Find the landmark, then start searching for the airport based on its position relative to the landmark, using other guides like road geometry.

If the airport is unfamiliar, you should fly over it 500ft above pattern/circuit altitude to reconnoitre things, like checking the overall placement of things, the wind sock, the apparent runway condition, etc. Join the circuit/pattern from the overhead.

Very important when going into an unfamiliar airport, especially an unlicensed private one where there may be power lines in unexpected places, look for the ***poles***, not the wires themselves (unless the wires have those orange marker balls).